# How to read javascript file error message

Tags: javascript

it is simple question,i'm getting error from js library such as ...js:2:1 unknown. Is that mean that the problem came from this file in line 2 column 1 or?

Comment: On which browser do you get this error message ? But yes, I think you interpret in correctly.

Comment: ie8 and in this position there is "use strict"

Comment: If you want us to resolve your javascript errors, please post a new question, including the full error message you got, on which browser  you got it and the javascript code associated.

Comment: I dont want that u resolve it, i never had such type of error and im wondering what it is. I answered that in that position is written "use strict". may be this the reason?

Comment: So you want me to resolve it :) As far as I know, `'use strict';` statement is supported by IE8. Again, as I said, edit your question or create a new one.